# using pandas isin with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe the looks like the following below. I want to be able to find out the  total number of "missing" that is occurring in the dataframe but to also group the data by columns A,B and C.

```
               A   B           C        D        E        F  total_missing
0     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball       21  MISSING  MISSING             11
1     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball       17  MISSING  MISSING             11
2     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball  MISSING       12       23             11
3  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball  MISSING        5  MISSING             11
4  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball       10  MISSING  MISSING             11
5  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball        5  MISSING  MISSING             11
```

This code below only gives back the total number of the words missing which is 11 and it appears in all the rows. I just want the total 11 to appear in one cell and to be able to group it by columns a,b and c which I am not sure how to do with the isin function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\ds_test\basketball.xlsx')
df['total_missing'] = df.isin(["MISSING"]).sum().sum()
print(df['total_missing'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want:

```
dfn = (
    df.assign(Total_missing=df.eq('MISSING').sum(axis=1))
      .groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['Total_missing'].sum()
      .reset_index()
)

               A   B           C  Total_missing
0     Miami Heat  FL  Basketball              5
1  Orlando Magic  FL  Basketball              6
```

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you! I was struggling with this for a while.